# trying to connect web API's to oracle db

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, oracle, asp.net-web-api

trying to connect web API to oracle DB.

I have successfully connected with SQL server but I have no idea about oracle DB.what I have done is=> created a controller and write a get and post API method in it. and on the web.config I have added connectionStrings. I am attaching my SQL connection code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;

namespace API2.Controllers
{
    public class IndexController : ApiController
        {
            [HttpGet]
            [Route("getUsers")]
            public HttpResponseMessage Get_Users()
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                string str_Msg = string.Empty;
                string Query = string.Empty;
                string consString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["xyz"].ConnectionString;
                Query = "SELECT * from xyz";
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand _SqlCommand = new SqlCommand(Query, con))
                    {
                        _SqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        using (SqlDataAdapter _adapater = new SqlDataAdapter(_SqlCommand))
                        {
                            _adapater.Fill(dt);

                        }
                        Query = string.Empty;
                    }
                }
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, dt, Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter);
            }
        }


<connectionStrings>
    <add name="xyz" connectionString="Data Source= xyz; Integrated Security=false;Initial Catalog= xyz; uid=xyz; Password=xyz;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I have no idea how to do the same connectivity with oracle DB. please help me with this.

thank you so much.

Comment: It seems like you want help on the connection string, am I right?

Comment: yes, I guess. btw I am a newbie in .net web API,

Comment: connection strings should be the same regardless of language (.net/java/python) and regardless of whether you have web interface or just a CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to [this](https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/)

Your connection string will look like

```
Data Source=MyOracleDB;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;Integrated Security=no;
```

Comment: what about these => using System.Data.SqlClient;using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
SqlConnection, SqlCommand and SqlDataAdapter  methods? did I have to use the same?

Comment: These should not be different.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. I have made some required change and it's working.